# Create synchronous loading of data using D3.js and drawing following the loading

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, d3.js, promise, async-await

I have reached a stage where I believe I am not understanding the correct callback of events. I am utilizing d3.js v5 and my issue is as follows.
I have a function which parses a tsv file and adds data to a global array `selectedData` using the `d3.tsv` function which utilizes promises within a function `addData`:

```
//function takes filename and data description to add to the selectedData global variable
function addData(filename, dataDesc) {
  d3.tsv(filename, type).then ((data) => {
    data.forEach(e => {
        var obj = {
            Title: dataDesc,
            ID: e.ID,
            Value: e.Value,
        }
        selectedData.push(obj);
    });
  });
}

function type(d) {
  d.Value = +d.Value;
}
```

Now I use this function to either add a single data file or can call it multiple times to add data from multiple data files into this global variable. The global variable is utilized for a number of other functions but as a start it is used to produce a bar chart.

For adding a single file, I would like to produce a bar chart after adding the data to the global variable. To do so I use the following function:

```
//functions adds one data file
function addOneData() {
  filename = userfile; //gets the user file name based on <input> element using the FileReader api
  dataDesc = document.getElementById('file_title').value; //gets the Descriptive Title of the data
  addData(filename, dataDesc); //add data to the global variable of selectedData
  drawBarChart(); //draws a grouped bar chart based on the global array of selectedData
}
```

I have a similar function which loops through an array of multiple data files as well to add them to the global variable with different `filenames` and `dataDesc`. For the multiple files I do not want the drawing to happen after each file, which is why the `drawBarChart` function is not a part of the `addData` function.

Now my issue is that the functions of `addData` and `drawBarChart` are running asynchronously and therefore `drawBarChart` runs much before the data is added to the `selectedData` global variable. So my question is, how can I make this either synchronous or use the power of promises? I have been trying promises and async/await but it feels like I am missing out on some key concepts. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*"Create synchronous loading of data"* is something that doesn't make much sense in this case... Instead of that, accept the nature of asynchronous code.

Also, you said:

> For the multiple files I do not want the drawing to happen after each file, which is why the drawBarChart function is not a part of the addData function.

But that's what your `addOneData` function is doing right now: it's calling `drawBarChart` for each file (wrongly, as you know, due to the asynchronous nature of `addData`).

So, let's fix your two problems, the asynchronous code and calling `drawBarChart` after loading multiple files.

#### 1. Asynchronous code

An easy solution is passing `drawBarchart` as a callback in another `then` method, like this:

```
function addData(filename, dataDesc, callback) {
  d3.json(filename).then((data) => {
    data.forEach(e => {
        var obj = {
            Title: dataDesc,
            Value: e
        }
        selectedData.push(obj);
    });
  }).then(callback)
};
```

Here is a demo with a very simple JSON I created online (which requires `d3.json`, but the general principle is the same of your `d3.tsv` and it works just as a TSV for your case):

```js
var selectedData = [];

addOneData();

function addData(filename, dataDesc, callback) {
  d3.json(filename).then((data) => {
    data.forEach(e => {
      var obj = {
        Title: dataDesc,
        Value: e
      }
      selectedData.push(obj);
    });
  }).then(callback)
};

function addOneData() {
  filename = "https://api.myjson.com/bins/m1vsl";
  dataDesc = "FooBar"
  addData(filename, dataDesc, drawBarChart);
};

function drawBarChart() {
  console.log(selectedData)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

#### 2. Multiple files

As you mentioned you may have many files, but you want to call `drawBarChart` only once. In that case, use `Promise.all` and an array with your filenames:

```
function addData(filenames, dataDesc, callback) {
  Promise.all(filenames.map(d => d3.json(d))).then((alldata) => {
    alldata.forEach(data => {
      data.forEach(e => {
        var obj = {
          Title: dataDesc,
          Value: e
        }
        selectedData.push(obj);
      });
    });
  }).then(callback)
};
```

Here is the demo:

```js
var selectedData = [];

addAllData();

function addData(filenames, dataDesc, callback) {
  Promise.all(filenames.map(d => d3.json(d))).then((alldata) => {
    alldata.forEach(data => {
      data.forEach(e => {
        var obj = {
          Title: dataDesc,
          Value: e
        }
        selectedData.push(obj);
      });
    });
  }).then(callback)
};

function addAllData() {
  filenames = ["https://api.myjson.com/bins/m1vsl", "https://api.myjson.com/bins/rncvp"];
  dataDesc = "FooBar";
  addData(filenames, dataDesc, drawBarChart);
};

function drawBarChart() {
  console.log(selectedData)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Gerardo, however if I have multiple files and I want to use the `drawBarChart` only once after loading all files it using a `for` statement I would not just be able to use the same callback. I suppose in that case I would have to put the `for` statement in a `Promise` and use `.then` and callback `drawBarChart` right?

Comment: Using `Promise.all` seems to be easier: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Could you expand the answer to include an example of if I can use it using the same `addData` function?

Comment: @Coola I just did it, check the second snippet.

Comment: The second snippet in it's current state would not be able to handle unique `dataDesc` for each file. As in this case only one `dataDesc` is sent in only once? How would I tackle that? The `dataDesc` is based on user input.

Comment: @Coola pass it as an array and use the index of the outer `forEach`.

Comment: I was actually thinking that as well but was just curious if that was the best solution. I suppose it is good enough. Will test it out. Thanks.